# Can't parse XML through JSTL using Google App Engine

Tags: xml, jsp, google-app-engine, xpath, jstl

After running my code I get the following error:

> **HTTP ERROR 500**
>
> Problem accessing /index.jsp. Reason:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathException

I correctly declared the taglibs in my **index.jsp** file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
```

Here is where I try to parse the XML file:

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:40rem;">
    <!-- Open Data -->
    <c:import var="sportInfo" url="http://data.nantes.fr/api/publication/24440040400129_NM_NM_00024/LOC_EQUIPUB_SPORT_NM_STBL/content/?format=xml"/>
    <x:parse xml="${sportInfo}" var="output"/>
    <x:forEach select="$output/document/data/element/geo/name" var="item">
        <option value="$output/document/data/element/_IDOBJ"><x:out select="$item" /></option>
    </x:forEach>
</select>
```

I have already checked online and tried different solutions, including adding Xalan to my project's build path, but so far no results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the appropriate Jars are on the classpath this might be pointing to incompatibilities between XPath and GAE (AKA Xpath uses some classes not [white listed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) ).

There a couple of open issues ([here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2180) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1370)) form people with your exact same problem, both issues have been ackwnoledged by the GAE team but unfortunately there is no solution so far.